# xml.etree.ElementTree findall() not behaving as expected

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> t = ET.fromstring('<root><field name="tcp.option_len" ></field></root>')
>>> t.findall('.//field [@name="tcp.option_len"]')
[]
```

Why isn't the `field` returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the space in the XPath query b/n field and the bracket [

```
 t.findall('.//field[@name="tcp.option_len"]')
```